# Regex Assistance - alphanumeric string separated by comma and/or space

Tags: regex

Need to have alphanumeric string separated by comma (needed) and/or space(not required to have it but user can enter and that is acceptable)

So, "ab1c,def2, efg657hi" is fine.
Prefer no leading trailing , or space, but not a show stopper

I have the following but don't think it's complete.

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]?+(,\s[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*
```

Comment: Try it without the `?` like `^[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:\s*,\s*[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*$` to match multiple characters https://regex101.com/r/vQzM3K/1

Comment: Use `^[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:,\s*[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*$`

Comment: @thefourthbird - thanks but https://regex101.com/r/sZ4cV5/13 - why does it allow special characters

Comment: @N.Kaufman Because there are no anchors `^` and `$` see https://regex101.com/r/WbKYSw/1 so it allows for partial matches.

Comment: @thefourthbird - thanks, my bad, I was using my regex instead of using yours. let me try Wiktor's regex as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `[0-9a-zA-Z]?+(,\s[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*` that you tried uses a [possessive quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) `?+` which means it either matches 1 character or no character, but when it matches it does not allow for backtracking.

As the second part is optional `(,\s[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*` the whole pattern can also match an empty string or for example a leading comma `, abd`

To make the pattern match the whole string, you can add anchors to prevent partial matches, and repeat the leading character class 1+ or more times.

If you also want to allow for optional whitespace chars before the comma you can add another `\s*` before it:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:\s*,\s*[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WbKYSw/1).

**Note** that `\s` can also match a newline.

Comment: The req has now changed a bit, Now they want to accept leading/trailing spaces and commas. Since the original ask has changed, should I create a new question and mark your response as the Answer for this one?

Comment: I have the following that allows leading/trailing commas/spaces
[,\s]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:\s*,\s*[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*[,\s]*$

Comment: please let me know if you see any issue with the latest regex that is based on the sample you provided

Comment: @N.Kaufman You can do that, it would allow mutiple spaces or comma's at the start and/or end of the string. See https://regex101.com/r/WDcgvL/1

Comment: thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

> *Need to have alphanumeric string separated by comma (needed) **and/or** space (not required to have it but user can enter and that is acceptable)*

I'd advise:

```
^(?!.*_)\w+(?:,? ?\w+)*$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/IkVxXi/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?!.*_)` - Negative lookahead to prevent 0+ characters and underscore.
- `\w+` - 1+ Word-characters, short for `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `,? ?` - Optional comma and optional space to allow for all variations mentioned, e.g. comma and/or space (not required).
  - `\w+` - 1+ Word-characters, short for `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`.
  - `)*` - Close non-capture group and match 0+ times.
- `$` - End string anchor.

---

Note that you could remove the negative lookahead and use the extended character class instead of `\w`.

Comment: You can make the lookahead fail a bit earlier using the negation `^(?![^\W_]*_)\w+(?:,? ?\w+)*$`